# Is there a way to use Sublime to show file previews in Windows Explorer for certain files?

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3

I'd like to be able to preview all plain-text files in the Windows File Explorer Preview Pane. To illustrate, here's what sublime files currently look like:

[image]

As you can see, `Context.sublime-menu` is highlighted, but a preview doesn't appear. They're just plain-text files though - you can open them in Notepad. Is there a way to tell windows "Use notepad (or sublime) to view this type of file the preview pane"?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/1151237/511640

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@KeithHall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473405/keith-hall)'s link - while it didn't work for me - got me started on a pretty long path to finally figuring this out. And finding a better solution than I thought existed.

In short, simply install the [Delphi Preview Handler](https://github.com/RRUZ/delphi-preview-handler). Which pretty much gives you an IDE in the preview pane. It's pretty simple to use and just awesome.

After installation, if you click on a `.js` file in Windows File Explorer you can immediately see a different preview pane.

---

## Registering Other Extensions

The Preview Handler doesn't compensate for all plain-text files unfortunately, so you're gonna have to manually add the sublime extensions and any other extensions in the Registry Editor.

**Here's the bird's-eye view of this process:**

1. Find the key/value that instructs Windows to use Delphi as the preview handler for `.js` files.
2. Copy the key/value
3. Apply that to each extension you want to preview.

**Here's more in-depth instructions:**

> First, you need to find the ID of the Preview Handler, and its Default Value

1. <kbd>win + r</kbd>`regedit` > expand `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`
2. Find `.js` and expand it.
3. `.js` should have a subkey named `shellex`, expand that

> You need to recreate this shellex key for each extension you want to add, so copy its contents:

1. `shellex` should have a **sub-key** named with a bunch of numbers, letters, and dashes, this is the ID of the preview pane (I think)
2. **Right-Click** that > **Rename** > **Copy** > **Cancel**
3. **Open** Sublime > **Create** a new file > **Paste**
4. Go back to the **Registry Editor**, **Click** that ID subkey, and a String value called `(Default)` should appear in the right side of the window.
5. **Double-Click** that
6. **Copy** > **Cancel** > **Paste** in sublime. This is the ID of the Preview Handler (I think).
7. At this point there should be 2 IDs in the sublime file.

> Now You're ready to add these same values to other extensions.

1. Find the extension(s) you want to change. For me it was all the sublime file-types.
2. **Right-click** > **New** > **Key** > call it `shellex`
3. Go to **sublime**, **copy** the first value
4. **Right-click** shellex > **New** > **Key** > **Paste**
5. Go to **sublime**, **copy** the second value
6. Click the new key and make it's default value that 2nd id.

So it should look similar to this:

```
v .sublime-commands
|   v shellex
|   |- {823BD1D4-...
```

And in the right side of the window:

```
Name            Type          Data
(Default)       REG_SZ        {AD9955...
```

---

**Sources:**

- [This Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1052930/232563) by [@rxantos](https://superuser.com/users/174618/rxantos) pointed me in the direction of the Delphi Preview Handler.
- I spent about an hour looking for [this app](https://superuser.com/a/877927/232563) but never found it.
- [This Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1151237/232563) by [@tvj247](https://superuser.com/users/638281/tyj247) is perhaps a more simple solution, but my HKey structure didn't match his (I'm using Windows 10).
- And as for fiddling with the Registry, that was trial, error, and comparing sublime extension keys to js, html and css.

Comment: can you post a full image that can explain what is "{AD9955..."